# Custom url for custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, urls

Is it possible to create a custom url for custom post types?

I have a directory website where in user can post or add a listing in many cities, I have a custom post type name ads. And all of the ads post titles are phone numbers. So when I create a new ads post in a city (e.g. Birmingham AL), the city will be save as a post meta `post_ads_city`,

Automatically the url will be mysite.com/ads/123-123-1234

Is it possible to make the url slug based on the city where the ads is posted? so it will be like this:

> mysite.com/birmingham-al/123-123-1234 (if the postmeta "post_ads_city"
>   = "Birmingham AL") mysite.com/las-vegas/123-123-1234 (if the postmeta "post_ads_city" = "Las Vegas")

Comment: you will save yourself lots of trouble by prefixing your structure with `ads`, so it it is `mysite.com/ads/birmingham-al/123-123-1234`. with your current desired structure, there's nothing to distinguish those requests from the page post type, all pages will 404.

Comment: i can do that, but the directory site i am doing is already live for 2 years now and it has been develop using codeigniter, so what im doing is recreating that site again into wordpress thats why i need to keep the urls the same for seo purposes

Answer (score 0):

Use [`add_rewrite_rule()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
        add_rewrite_rule('^nutrition/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=12&food=$matches[1]&variety=$matches[2]','top');
    }
    add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

you can use `if ( 'myposttype' == $post->post_type ){}` to make it post type specific.  Weather you want to add it inside the function or wrapping the add action is up to you.

Comment: can you show an example of using `if ( 'myposttype' == $post->post_type ){}` to make it post type specific? (this is sort of a trick question- it's not possible)

Comment: @Milo you would know better than me!  I guess there are a bunch of ways to examine this, this post outlines it more: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-rewrite-rules-for-custom-post-types